# the two constructors of pair is almost the same, why not generate build error?

Tags: c++, templates, overloading

In pair's implemention, next two constructors only differ in the prefix: explicit. the two member template function is almost the same.

```
template<class _Other1,
        class _Other2,
        enable_if_t<conjunction_v<
            is_constructible<_Ty1, _Other1>,
            is_constructible<_Ty2, _Other2>,
            is_convertible<_Other1, _Ty1>,
            is_convertible<_Other2, _Ty2>
        >, int> = 0>
        constexpr pair(_Other1&& _Val1, _Other2&& _Val2)
            _NOEXCEPT_COND(is_nothrow_constructible_v<_Ty1, _Other1>
                && is_nothrow_constructible_v<_Ty2, _Other2>)
        : first(_STD forward<_Other1>(_Val1)),
                second(_STD forward<_Other2>(_Val2))
        {   // construct from moved values
        }

    template<class _Other1,
        class _Other2,
        enable_if_t<conjunction_v<
            is_constructible<_Ty1, _Other1>,
            is_constructible<_Ty2, _Other2>,
            negation<conjunction<
                is_convertible<_Other1, _Ty1>,
                is_convertible<_Other2, _Ty2>>>
        >, int> = 0>
        constexpr explicit pair(_Other1&& _Val1, _Other2&& _Val2)
            _NOEXCEPT_COND(is_nothrow_constructible_v<_Ty1, _Other1>
                && is_nothrow_constructible_v<_Ty2, _Other2>)
        : first(_STD forward<_Other1>(_Val1)),
                second(_STD forward<_Other2>(_Val2))
        {   // construct from moved values
        }
```

But when I write my test example as follows:

```
class A
{
public:
    template<typename T1,typename T2>
    A(T1 a,T2 b){}

    template<typename T1,typename T2>
    explicit A(T1 a,T2 b){}
};
```

A build error comes out as:

```
Error   C2535   'A::A(T1,T2)': member function already defined
```

So why the result differs?

Comment: The enable_if_t part is different?

Answer (score 2):

The class below does not use the template above.

The error is caused by the fact that you're describing the same constructor twice.

`explicit` is just a limitation how a constructor can be called, not a signature change that would allow an overload.

Comment: but why the two same constructors in pair don't report error?

Comment: Here's my better guess: because the first constructor is only instantiated when `is_convertible<_Other1, _Ty1>` and `is_convertible<_Other2, _Ty2>`, the second - in the opposite case.

Answer (score 2):

The difference is not just in the use of `explicit`, there is also a different condition in the template arguments to `enable_if_t`:

```
//     Constructor 1                            Constructor 2
enable_if_t<conjunction_v<               enable_if_t<conjunction_v<
  is_constructible<_Ty1, _Other1>,         is_constructible<_Ty1, _Other1>,
  is_constructible<_Ty2, _Other2>,         is_constructible<_Ty2, _Other2>,
  is_convertible<_Other1, _Ty1>,           negation<conjunction<
  is_convertible<_Other2, _Ty2>              is_convertible<_Other1, _Ty1>,
                                             is_convertible<_Other2, _Ty2>>>
```

The first constructor is called if all four conditions are true (`_Ty1/2` can be constructed from `_Other1/2` and `_Other1/2` can be converted to `_Ty1/2`). The second one is called only if the latter two conditions are false.

`explicit` in itself does not affect overload resolution, it just means the constructor can only be used in direct-initialization contexts.